# What is distinctive for functors compared to normal functions taking values as arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

I am newbie for the concept but as I search the difference and the good of the functors is that they are able to store values inside and initialize these values from the construction but normal functions also work in same fashion except they take the all arguments as whole at the function call. Most probably I am wrong in some way but where is the trick and the benefit of functors in relation to normal functions

Comment: What is the distinction between apples and fruits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core difference is that a functor defines a type not a function. Even stateless functors (without any attached data) can take advantage of this. For example consider the use of `std::less` inside a sorting algorithm:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Comparator>
sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Comparator c) {
...
   if (c(*begin,*end)) { ...
...
}
```

Called as `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<int>());`. When the function is called, an instance of `std::less<int>` is created and passed to the template. Because it is stateless, the cost of passing the function is almost nothing. Inside the function, the call `c(a,b)` is determined to be a call to `c.operator()(a,b)`, and the compiler knows the type. It can efficiently inline the call (which in this case is simple enough) and substitute it by a single compare instruction.

On the other hand, the equivalent C function `qsort` takes a function pointer (you cannot pass functions by value). Inside `qsort`, the compiler does not know what the function called is, and it cannot inline it, so it must perform a function call for each comparison.

Functors serve both to add extra information that can later be used at the place of call (this is impossible with a plain function), and to pass extra information like provide information like what needs to be called (the same behavior can be obtained, but with a hit on performance) or other attached information (the type can have nested types/typedefs, information for traits inspection...)

Comment: It's true that `std::less` is stateless, but there is no requirement that callable objects be stateless. Stateful object are a bit tricky to use, because there are no guarantees about where and how often they are coped. So a stageful callable object would typically hold a pointer to its state rather than holding the state directly.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Agreed, I might not have been clear enough: for functors with state, there is no option. For stateless functors, that could be implemented either as a type or a function pointer, the use of a functor provides more information to the compiler that can further optimize code.

Answer (score 1):

Normal functions, free-standing or member, only have their arguments which will be passed when the function is called. So there is no way to pass extra data to the function.

This is different with a functor. A functor is an instance of an object, and as such can indeed store data passed to its constructor (which you use when passing the functor).

With C++11 things are muddled up a bit, as lambdas can also "store" (not technically correct word) values by using captures. Or by using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) which allows you to bind values as arguments when the callable object is actually called.